# Disable apollo rest parameters camelCase conversion

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Apollo client converts rest parameters into snake_case. How can I disable it?

This my mutation:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

      export const CREATE = gql`
      mutation create(
        $name: String
        $email: String
      ) {
        account(input: { fields: [
          { 
            fieldId: name
            value: $name
          },
          { 
            fieldId: email
            value: $email
          }
        ] 
        })
          @rest(
            type: "gateway"
            path: "/auth/gateway/create"
            method: "POST"
          ) {
          __typename
        }
      }
    `
```

where `fieldId` is converted into `field_id`. I need to use camelCase format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a [pull request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-rest/pull/29/files#diff-f901259277ba5c8432f713c98af5a1baR1323) with `fieldNameDenormalizer` parameter. You need to add `fieldNameDenormalizer: $requestLevelDenormalizer` into mutation and define `requestLevelDenormalizer` as a function which converts string into camelCase.